# Django migration id char column to existing table

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create an ID charfield column and set it as primary key to an existing table. So because it is an existing table when i generate Migrations django asks me to provide a default value. What can i enter as primary key default for existing rows? If i enter a single string e.x 'abcd' i will get error for existing rows on migrate because of duplicate value

Answer (score 0):

Apologies.

I didn't read correctly.